# nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset when downloading large applicaiton

Tags: java, spring, nolio

Im getting "nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"

when exporting an applicaion where the export last more than five minutes. Client pops up with the error message, but on the server side the export continues and finishes successfully. Connecting the ASAP with the direct address of the application server does not produces issues, only if we use the alias address via the F5 loadbalancer, do we need need to update any to rectify this issue.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
SwingWorker-pool-18484408-thread-37] ERROR (ExportForm.java:249) - error exporting element Generic JBoss to file C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\export.dat Could not access HTTP invoker remote service at [http://nolio-test:80/datamanagement/remoting/ExportImportService]; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access HTTP invoker remote service at [http://nolio-test:80/datamanagement/remoting/ExportImportService]; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.convertHttpInvokerAccessException(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:212)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.nolio.platform.server.dataservices.services.auth.NolioHttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean.invoke(NolioHttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean.java:14)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.exportApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
    at com.nolio.platform.aspects.ProfilingAspect.invoke(ProfilingAspect.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.exportApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.nolio.platform.shared.app.view.impexp.ExportForm$4.exportElement(ExportForm.java:311)
    at com.nolio.platform.shared.app.view.impexp.ExportForm$4.doInBackground(ExportForm.java:246)
    at com.jidesoft.utils.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.utils.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:77)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1110)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1391)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1824)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1584)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:995)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:393)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:168)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:393)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.executePostMethod(CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:205)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.doExecuteRequest(CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:140)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.executeRequest(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:192)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:142)
    ... 32 more
2015-08-17 13:16:19,162 [RequestsDispatcher-1-thread-4] DEBUG (JobTracker.java:101) - Job Tracker cycle: 0 jobs to track.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fGNb.jpg
```

Comment: Sounds like the client is timing out.

Comment: Sounds to me like the server is ignoring  error codes.

Comment: Some server side code would be nice.

Comment: Did you try to give the ASAP process more memory? You can do that by editing the ASAP launcher jsp file.